# Discord.py bot.get_all_members not working

Tags: python, discord.py

Got no clue whats wrong with this i just want it to list all the people in the discord in the terminal

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
bot  = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '£', intents=intents) 


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print (f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    print (bot.get_all_members)
```

Comment: It's a function, you're supposed to call it...

Comment: so how can i make it print off all the members

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of [HamsterRecords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69471680/11529410) response, you should be able to use list comprehension:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print (f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    print ([member for member in bot.get_all_members()])
```

Comment: yeah this works well but it gives me a bunch of junk i dont want i only want the name number and guild number and name any way i can get rid of the rest

Comment: Then you need to look at the [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_all_members#discord.Member) documentation and choose which field you want to print.

Comment: ok cheers for the help

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `bot.get_all_members` works,
if you check out the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_all_members#discord.Client.get_all_members) you can see it needs to be used in an for loop.However you could just use the example below which functions in the similar way as get_all_members() (there is probably a faster and more efficient way but I can't think of anything better right now)

```py
all_members = []
for guild in bot.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        all_members.append(member.name)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print (f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    print (all_members)
```

**Edit** 
Like as @Dominik said:
For `guild.members` you need to have member intent enabled, otherwise its going to output an empty list

Comment: Thank you very much but now its saying there is no one in the server its in

Comment: You also need to enable Intents.

Comment: @IDEADZOMBIE For this you need to enable member intent (for guild.members)

Comment: i have enabled it i believe i did it on the code and on the bot in the portal

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `len(bot.users)` to grab the total amount of users that your bot can see. Like that:

```
print(len(bot.users))
```

---

### Sources

- [Client.users](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=users#discord.Client.users)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
len(set(bot.get_all_members()))
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/ConchDev/ConchBot/blob/66702ea3873a41e19de6d9f5858ecf5cdd419e44/bot/bot.py#L68